# python - printing else statement rather then if and not repeating while statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a program that finds the multiple of a number between 1 and 10. The code currently skips over the if statement and immediately performs the else statement which is an error message even if an "accepted" value is entered. I also need it to repeat the multiples until it gets to 100 or above then it should stop. I tried changing around the ands and ors with no success and swapped the if and while statements around again to no success. The program looks like this:

```
check3 = False
num = int(input("Enter a number between 1 and 10: "))
if num <= 10 or num >= 1:
    while not num <= 100:
       num += num
       print(num)
    
    else:
        print("Not in range. Try again.")
```

Comment: `num <= 10 or num >= 1` read that again and really think about what it's doing. Also fix your indentation

Comment: There are multiple typos and basic logical errors here. Please review your notes and try to make the program work one step at a time. Write *even less* code at a time and *make sure it works*. For example, try to write code that *only* reads the input and tells you what it was. Then *only* add the part that checks that the value is in range (use a `print` to confirm both sides of the `if`). Then *only* add the loop.

Comment: Also, your `else` should be indented at the same level as `if`.

Comment: `while not num <= 100` also needs another look. If you enter a number between 1 and 10, will it ever be _not_ less than 100?

Comment: `or` should be `and`. Didn't you post the same question a couple of hours ago?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like multiple people commented, there are a couple of problems.
I will walk you through them and then provide a commented working example.

##### Code walkthrough

```py
check3 = False
num = int(input("Enter a number between 1 and 10: "))
# This condition can be rewritten without or/and to make it simpler to understand
# Check example below.
# (Also, if you were to write it like this, 
#   then the if would execute if either condition is true. 
#   Meaning it would execute if num is -50 because -50 <= 10.)
if num <= 10 or num >= 1:
    # This while will run when NOT (number less than 100)
    # So the while will only run when number is greater than 100
    # You want the opposite of this actually
    while not num <= 100:
        # If you keep adding num to itself you will not get the multiples
        # Example: num = 10
        # round 1: num = 10+10 (num is now 20)
        # round 2: num = 20+20 (num is now 40)
        # etc
        num += num
        print(num)
    # This else is indented at the same level as the while...
    # So it will actually trigger when the condition is false.
    else:
        print("Not in range. Try again.")
```

So basically what's happening when you run your code is that since num is less than 100, the while will not run and execution will jump to the else.

##### Working example

```py
num = int(input("Enter a number between 1 and 10: "))
if 1 <= num <= 10:

    # it's better to set another variable because if you keep doing num+=num
    # for num = 10 you will get num = 10+10 on the first loop (so num is 20 now)
    # num = 20 + 20 on the second loop, etc...
    multiples = 0
    while not multiples >= 100:
        multiples += num
        print(multiples)

# the else needs to be indented at the same level as the if
else:
    print("Not in range. Try again.")
```

##### End notes on boolean logic:

A `OR` B is true if either are true or if both are true.
A `AND` B is only true if both are true.

Comment: the `else` actually triggers for loops that don't call `break`, not for a while loop that has a false condition

Comment: Well, yes, but "has a false condition" is *why* a `while` loop doesn't reach `break`. (It could also `return`, or raise an exception, but of course in that case we don't reach the `else` either.)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Ok so the else will always trigger unless we prevent the execution from reaching it and has nothing to do with the while condition per se. Because a while with a true condition will always reach the else if we don't write any specific shenanigans... right?

Comment: No. When the condition is false, the loop is exited, and the `else` runs. It doesn't matter whether `break` *appears within* the loop; it only matters whether the `break` *happens*. If the condition is always true and there is also no `break`, `return` or exception, then that's just an infinite loop.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel So a while loop exiting normally because the condition became false also counts as a `break` _happening_ have I interpreted correctly?

Comment: No. There are five things that can happen: 1. Loop never exits. 2. Exception is raised (`else` block does not run, because it goes right to the exception handler). 3. `return` happens (`else` block does not run, because we leave the function completely). 4. `break` happens (`else` block does not run, because that's the purpose of the block). 5. the loop exits normally because the condition became false (this is the only time the `else` block runs).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! I learned a lot!

Comment: this didnt completely work, it prints a zero at the start of the out put and thats not what I want. I need it to print from the number given, all the way to the highest multiple before or even with 100

Comment: Ah, was confused over the wording of "when the condition is false" (e.g. initial check only) vs "once" (e.g. at any check) hadn't really thought of the else in that way (for me I thought of it as an else for "<if the loop was aborted>", but yours is a valid mental model, and easier to explain :)